# How to format the export button in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to format the exporting "contextButton" in Highcharts?  (Specifically to look more like other buttons on a page.)  I do not mean creating a new button with new functionality, I mean the exact functionality of the standard exporting contextButton, I just want to change basic css like colors.  Thanks.

```
exporting: {
  enabled: true,
  buttons: {
      contextButton: {
          text: 'Export',
          color: '#f00',  // this does nothing
      },
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the context button is at...

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.contextButton

If you want to change the color of the symbol on the button then use the symbol attributes. For example...

```
        exporting: {
            enabled: true,
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    text: 'Export',
                    symbolFill: '#f88',
                    symbolStroke: '#f00'
                }
            }
        }
```

If you want to change the color of the button then use the theme attribute. For example...

```
        exporting: {
            enabled: true,
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    text: 'Export',
                    theme: {
                        fill: '#ddd',
                        stroke: '#888',
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                fill: '#fcc',
                                stroke: '#f00'
                            },
                            select: {
                                fill: '#cfc',
                                stroke: '#0f0'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```